# If two processes receive both hold a reference to the same object they they synchronize over it in java?

Tags: blackberry, java-me, synchronized

This issue Originates in the BlackBerry java world, where all processes live inside the SAME JVM and are able to pass object around to each other via a GlobalEventListener Interface : http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.0.2api/net/rim/device/api/system/GlobalEventListener.html

So, an object pass over that interface, will a synchronized block behave as intended? IE only one thread/process is allowed in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if they are the same object instance in the same jvm, then yes.